# tezos node doesnot sync up

Tags: node, octez

I have been trying to start the ghostnet node using  docker-compose but the node doesnot seem to sync with the latest height. when i query the head block, it returns the genesis block. Here is the config of the docker-compose file. I have not used the full history mode. I have been trying to use the rolling mode with history of only one epoch.. still the node doesnot sync.

```
version: "3.4"
volumes:
  node_data_full:
    name: ghostnet-node
    external: false  
  client_data:
    name: ghostnet-client
    external: false
services:
####################################################################################################################################
# You have to uncomment this section if you want to synchronize your node using a snapshot, else you can ignore or delete it.
# Replace /absolute/path/to/your_snapshot.full:/snapshot by the absolute path to the downloaded snapshot.
###################################################################################################################################  
#  import:
#    image: tezos/tezos:latest
#    container_name: octez-snapshot-import
#    command: octez-snapshot-import
#    volumes:
#      - node_data_full:/var/run/tezos/node
#      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
#      - "/absolute/path/to/your_snapshot.full:/snapshot"
################################################################################################
# If you want to run a node with history-mode=full, keep that "node_full" part, else delete it.
# You can change the version of the image of tezos in : image: tezos/tezos:v16.1
# You can change the --network=NETWORK option.
################################################################################################
  node_full:
    container_name: octez-public-node-full
    image: tezos/tezos:latest
    command: octez-node --network ghostnet --net-addr :9732 --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732 --allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:8732 --history-mode=rolling:1
    ports:
    - '9732:9732'
    - '8732:8732'
    expose:
    - "8732"
    - "9732" 
    privileged: true
    volumes:
     - node_data_full:/var/run/tezos/node
     - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
     - /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb
    restart: on-failure
    network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried exactly the same configuration you provided and it works. But it took 40 minutes for the node to finish fetching headers and start synchronizing. It's recommended to restore a node from a snapshot (you can uncomment the `import' section for this).